# after pressing lock key video seek state reset

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am facing issue related to VideoView that it is reseting to initial position after coming back from lock key interrupt.  I am providing my src code as below for your reference :

```
public class BNAboutVideoActivity extends Activity {

private MediaController mMediaController;
VideoView mVideoView;
private BNAudioManager mBNAudioManager;
int position = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_video);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    mBNAudioManager = BNAudioManager.getInstance(this);     
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.bn_about_video);

    mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);

    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.start();


    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            finish();
            if(BNAboutAdapter.bAboutPause)
            {
                mBNAudioManager.resumePlayer();
                BNAboutAdapter.bAboutPause = false;
            }
        }
    });

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onBackPressed()
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(BNAboutAdapter.bAboutPause)
    {
        mBNAudioManager.resumePlayer();
        BNAboutAdapter.bAboutPause = false;
    }
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onPause()
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    position = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
    mVideoView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mVideoView.seekTo(position); 
    mVideoView.resume();
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Can you please guide me.

Comment: What is with the finish() call in onCompletion callback? Probably that is the problem

Comment: I have called finish() in onCompletion callback so that i can go to my previous screen from where i played video when video finished. Note : video state is retaining if i came back by pressing home button. I am facing issue only when i came back by pressing lock key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call finish() in onCompletion callback() and when you re-enter the Activity onCreate() will be executed and so the video restarts from the beginning! finish() destroys the Activity and so the position is lost(when the app passes through onResume(), the position will be 0). You should reconsider persisting your video state. Probably it is better not to destroy the activity.

Another issue that I see in you code is regarding the code within onBackPressed(). Why do you want to resume your video in onBackPressed()? onBackPressed() is the same with the native back button that all android devices have, and practically it destroys your activity. You don't want to deal with resuming stuffs inside onBackPressed, but more with persisting data.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But onCompletion callback() is not called in my defect scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand the activity lifecycle when lock key is pressed.

on pressing lock key:

```
onPause -> onStop -> onDestroy
```

thus the current activity is destroyed and recreated to run with new configuration.

Explanation by **Dianne Hackborn**:

> The reason an activity is destroyed and re-created is to run it with a
>   new configuration.  You haven't said all that much about what you are
>   doing so it is hard to know what is going on, but I would assume that
>   you have forced an orientation for your activity, and the lock screen
>   has a different orientation.  So when the device goes to sleep, the
>   lock screen is displayed and forces an orientation and your activity
>   (which is still running at the top of the activity stack) now needs to
>   be restarted with the new orientation.
>
> The first thing is -- your activity really just needs to work
>   correctly when this happens.  If it doesn't, then you will see these
>   same bugs in other cases.  For example if the user plugs in a keyboard
>   causing a config change.  Or changes the locale.  Or font size.  And
>   on and on.
>
> Now assuming your activity is actually working correctly, if there is
>   a kind of config change you really don't care about you can use
>   android:configChanges in your activity in the manifest to say it
>   should not be restarted when specific kinds of changes happen.

[Refere this for complete thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Guv6-p4ujrE)

Hence you need to use following with your activity in your manifest, if you are targeting API level greater than 13.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

This should solve the issue.

If the issue still remains, then I would suggest a workaround as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{    

// used to listen for intents which are sent after a task was
// successfully processed
private BroadcastReceiver mUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // TODO: Put the current position in sharedpreference.

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // TODO: Fetch the value from sharedpreference.
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {  

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    // to listen when screen is unlocked
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    // to listen when screen is locked
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(mUpdateReceiver, filter);

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {     
    unregisterReceiver(mUpdateReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}   

}
```

Give it a try, Good luck.